# Getting Windmill Failed errors in Dataflow Jobs logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

[We are getting the following errors in our google cloud dataflow and jobs:

"Error while processing a work item: INTERNAL: Windmill failed to commit the work item. CommitStatus: NOT_FOUND
=== Source Location Trace: ===
dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/streaming/streaming_worker_client.cc:486"][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF2PU.png)

Comment: Are there any updates on this? I'm having the same error and have tried to follow the source location trace but there's no further information. It looks to be a Dataflow Harness issue though.